# Jmeter - how to pass cookie captured in one thread to another thread

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am trying to use same cookie(i.e. capturing cookies in main thread and trying to pass it in support threads) in different threads in Jmeter. I have already read the article give at

https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell

but its not working in my case. Can someone please help in recognizing what mistake I am doing while implementing the logic given in above link.
please find below steps I am following

```
  Test Plan  
     - HTTP Cache Manager           
     - HTTP Header Manager         
     - HTTP Cookie Manager        
     - Main Thread(login page under main thread)                           
        - Login (BeanShell PostProcessor under login)   
           - BeanShell PostProcessor  
         import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
         CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
         props.put("cookiecount", String.valueOf(manager.getCookieCount()));
         for (int i = 0; i < manager.getCookieCount(); i++)        
         {  
            props.put("cookie_name" + i, manager.get(i).getName());
            props.put("cookie_value" + i, manager.get(i).getValue());
            props.put("cookie_domain" + i, manager.get(i).getDomain());
            props.put("cookie_path" + i, manager.get(i).getPath());
            props.put("cookie_expires" + i, String.valueOf(manager.get(i).getExpires()));
            props.put("cookie_secure" + i, String.valueOf(manager.get(i).getSecure()));  
         }

     - Support Thread 1
          - BeanShell PreProcessor
              import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
              import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
              import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;
    CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
    int count = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("cookiecount"));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(props.getProperty("cookie_name" + i), 
                  props.getProperty("cookie_value" + i),
                props.getProperty("cookie_domain" + i), 
                props.getProperty("cookie_path" + i),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("cookie_secure" + i)),
                Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("cookie_expires" + i)));
                manager.add(cookie);
    }
    JMeterProperty cookieprop = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager");
    cookieprop.setObjectValue(manager);
    ctx.getCurrentSampler().setProperty(cookieprop);
           - HTTP Request
```

After running it for 1 thread - 1 loop getting different cookies for both threads something like below

```
- Main Thread 
  Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=PvRSWmBXNp9y65njGkRWbLlxLM1pvxLzpnyjThQDny3pMy6Gkcjv!486373045

- Support Thread
  Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=YVGsWmQSXdGt1xqfDDvlkgkHLpqJ3WRD2sDyqXp62rChfTDbM0Vj!486373045
```

I have set CookieManager.save.cookies=true.

Comment: So you are wanting to have the same cookies every time?

Comment: Yes.
I want to use same cookie in support thread which is creating in main thread when it was initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 different HTTP Cookie Manager test elements for different thread groups.

---

P.S. If you already have `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property set and you know cookie names - you can use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to pass variables which hold cookie values between thread groups like:

- In 1st Thread Group convert variable to property like `${__setProperty(JSESSIONID,COOKIE_JSESSIONID,)}`
- In 2nd Thread Group refer the property as `${__P(JSESSIONID,)}`

The approach is described in details in the  [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article.

Comment: I can't use 2 different HTTP Cookie Manager as I want to use same cookie in both the threads. e.g. Main Thread is using cookie xxxxxxxxxx1234 same should be used in Support Thread xxxxxxxxxx1234.